# How to get the integer value of all days of week using DateTimeFormat.DayNames? c#

Tags: c#, datetimeformatinfo

I'm using `DateTimeFormatInfo.DayNames` Property to get all day Names of a week , I would like to get the id of the days of week , I have seen many answers but I'm searching for a solution using this property .

How can I get the integer of all days of week ?

```
  days_in_arabic = new CultureInfo("ar-AE").DateTimeFormat.DayNames; 

//  this will return the days of week in arabic format.
```

**Update:**

My question now will be how can I get the index of the enum `DayOfWeek` to store it into an array of integer?

How can I get an array as an output like this :

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

and this array should be compatible with the days of week , I have already a Combobox that filled by an array of days , so I need to store the index of these days selected from the combobox into the database.

[image]

- According to the answer of @JL0PD.

  ```
  var daysid = Enum.GetNames(typeof(DayOfWeek));
        var daysid2 = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek));

        foreach(string name in daysid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Day1 is " + name);

        }
        foreach(var day2 in daysid2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Day2 is " + day2);

        }
  ```

I have tested what he said in the comment and this what I got:

```
Day1 is Sunday
Day1 is Monday
Day1 is Tuesday
Day1 is Wednesday
Day1 is Thursday
Day1 is Friday
Day1 is Saturday
Day2 is Sunday
Day2 is Monday
Day2 is Tuesday
Day2 is Wednesday
Day2 is Thursday
Day2 is Friday
Day2 is Saturday
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply do this to get the values of the `DayOfWeek` enum:

```
int[] values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

Or:

```
int[] values = typeof(DayOfWeek).GetEnumValues().Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you , just one remark, is there any possibility to use `DateTimeFormatInfo` Class instead of `DayOfWeek` Enum??

Comment: @csharp_devloper31 - It doesn't seem to be there.

Answer (score 1):

If think the array you get will be in the same order as the "DayOfWeek" enum.
So following the natural order and beginning with Sunday.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=net-5.0

Re-Edit :
Proposed solution by @Enigmativity in comment:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Cast<int>().ToArray()
```

Comment: It really irks me that MS choose Sunday to be the first day of the week. According to ISO 8601, *Monday* is the first day of the week.

Comment: Can confirm: Days from `DateTimeFormat.DayNames` is same as in `Enum.GetNames(typeof(DayOfWeek))` or `Enum.GeValues(typeof(DayOfWeek))` at least with net5

Comment: My question will be now , how can I get the index of days from the Enum of `DayOfWeek`

Comment: This method should do the work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-5.0

Comment: Just realized @JL0PD gave the answer in the previous comment.

Comment: @Arcord , not exactly what I need , I'm still getting the name of the days of a week , I need the index of the names. I will update my answer

Comment: I udpated my answer, should be what you want.

Comment: `Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Cast<int>().ToArray();` works just fine thanks to LINQ's `Cast` operator.

Comment: Indeed I forgot the Cast operator and the Select was not available since it's not a generic IEnumerable.